# Why does my text align in Safari and Chrome but not Internet Explorer/Firefox?

Tags: css

My website is [wordswithfriends.net](http://www.wordswithfriends.net)

In Safari/Chrome in the sidebar e.g. "Monthly Countdown" the headers and text lineup exactly. In IE/Firefox the header is more to the right and the text is pushed all the way to the left.  What is wrong with my code?

Edit css:

```
#sidebar h3 {
background: url (images/sidebarh3bgr.png) no repeat;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 0 0 10px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 18px;
}

#sidebar li .top {
padding: 0px 0px 15px 1px;
width: 333px;
background: no-repeat url(images/bcksidebarlitop.png);
}

.execphpwidget {
margin: 10px 23px 0px 10px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
}

.textwidget {
padding: 5px 5px 5px 17px;
}

#sidebar ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 3px 17px;
}
```

Comment: Looks exactly the same to me in FF/Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebug in Firefox and Developer Tools in IE both show that the style defined for your class*`.execphpwidget` is not being applied.  Neither inspection method indicates that the style is being overridden; it's just not present.

A quick validation of your style sheet shows that you have some bad CSS towards the end, around line 470:
`img .alignnone size-full wp-image-364 {float:right; padding:5px 10px 10px 0px;"}`

See here:
[W3C CSS Validation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwordswithfriends.net%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fvibe%2Fstyle.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)

Because of this error, IE and Firefox are discarding the remainder of your style sheet, which includes the left padding/margin that you are missing.

I guess Chrome and Safari are more forgiving.

Answer (score 1):

Css-reset is the magic word :-)

Every Browser has his own default CSS. Thats one of the biggest problems for web developer.

For example a CSS-Reset sets many properties to 0px (`margin:0;padding:0;`)